# Kafka Consumer: I am getting the same messages over and over again, as if there's no committing what I've already read

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Here's my source

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import struct as _struct
import sys
from time import sleep

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
     'stringtest',
     bootstrap_servers=['10.100.121.134:9092'],
     enable_auto_commit=True,
     auto_commit_interval_ms=1000,
     group_id='my-group',
     max_poll_records=1,
     max_poll_interval_ms=1000,
     key_deserializer=lambda x: _struct.unpack('>q', x)[0],
     value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))

for message in consumer:
    print("Key = " + str(message.key) + ", Value = " + message.value + ", Topic = " + message.topic)
    if message.value == 'STOP':
        sleep(3)
        sys.exit(0)
```

I have a list of a few messages in the topic `stringtest`, and when I run the program it gives me the list of messages (the last one of which is `STOP`), and stops. Then, when I run it again, it gives me the same list of messages. How can I prevent this? I thought the sleep() will give the commit time to tell Kafka that this consumer has already read these messages, but it doesn't work this way. What am I missing?

Comment: Try closing consumer upon exit - `consumer.close()`

Comment: OK. this worked (but only after I added the `consumer.close()` before the `sleep`. It needed the sleep after the close). Thanks a lot.